# TensorFlow Keras CuDNNGRU to GRU conversion

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras

I have a trained model built in TensorFlow 1.14 using the (now-deprecated) [`tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CuDNNGRU) layer (available in TensorFlow 2.0 in [`tf.compat.v1`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNGRU)), and I am trying to port the old layer's weights into a new TensorFlow 2.0 model built using [`tf.keras.layers.GRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) to get an equivalent model.

One motivation for doing this is being able to do inference on a CPU (the `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU` layer only runs on a GPU). The other motivation is future-proofing the model.

## Question

How can I turn a trained `tf.contrib.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU` layer into an equivalent `tf.keras.layers.GRU` layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following private helper function in [`tensorflow.python.keras.saving.hdf5_format`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c52ee536c045186476450cf76461d47fb2667e7d/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py#L404-L568) appears to do the trick. The function performs the more general task of converting weights between `CuDNNGRU`/`GRU` and `CuDNNLSTM`/`LSTM` formats, so it is useful beyond just my use case. The function appears to have originated in [this pull request](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9112) in standalone Keras.

````py
import numpy as np


def _convert_rnn_weights(layer, weights):
  """Converts weights for RNN layers between native and CuDNN format.

  Input kernels for each gate are transposed and converted between Fortran
  and C layout, recurrent kernels are transposed. For LSTM biases are summed/
  split in half, for GRU biases are reshaped.

  Weights can be converted in both directions between `LSTM` and`CuDNNSLTM`
  and between `CuDNNGRU` and `GRU(reset_after=True)`. Default `GRU` is not
  compatible with `CuDNNGRU`.

  For missing biases in `LSTM`/`GRU` (`use_bias=False`) no conversion is made.

  Arguments:
      layer: Target layer instance.
      weights: List of source weights values (input kernels, recurrent
          kernels, [biases]) (Numpy arrays).

  Returns:
      A list of converted weights values (Numpy arrays).

  Raises:
      ValueError: for incompatible GRU layer/weights or incompatible biases
  """


  def transform_kernels(kernels, func, n_gates):
    """Transforms kernel for each gate separately using given function.

    Arguments:
        kernels: Stacked array of kernels for individual gates.
        func: Function applied to kernel of each gate.
        n_gates: Number of gates (4 for LSTM, 3 for GRU).

    Returns:
        Stacked array of transformed kernels.
    """
    return np.hstack([func(k) for k in np.hsplit(kernels, n_gates)])


  def transpose_input(from_cudnn):
    """Makes a function that transforms input kernels from/to CuDNN format.

    It keeps the shape, but changes between the layout (Fortran/C). Eg.:

    ```
    Keras                 CuDNN
    [[0, 1, 2],  <--->  [[0, 2, 4],
     [3, 4, 5]]          [1, 3, 5]]
    ```

    It can be passed to `transform_kernels()`.

    Arguments:
        from_cudnn: `True` if source weights are in CuDNN format, `False`
            if they're in plain Keras format.

    Returns:
        Function that converts input kernel to the other format.
    """
    order = 'F' if from_cudnn else 'C'


    def transform(kernel):
      return kernel.T.reshape(kernel.shape, order=order)


    return transform


  target_class = layer.__class__.__name__


  # convert the weights between CuDNNLSTM and LSTM
  if target_class in ['LSTM', 'CuDNNLSTM'] and len(weights) == 3:
    # determine if we're loading a CuDNNLSTM layer
    # from the number of bias weights:
    # CuDNNLSTM has (units * 8) weights; while LSTM has (units * 4)
    # if there's no bias weight in the file, skip this conversion
    units = weights[1].shape[0]
    bias_shape = weights[2].shape
    n_gates = 4


    if bias_shape == (2 * units * n_gates,):
      source = 'CuDNNLSTM'
    elif bias_shape == (units * n_gates,):
      source = 'LSTM'
    else:
      raise ValueError('Invalid bias shape: ' + str(bias_shape))


    def convert_lstm_weights(weights, from_cudnn=True):
      """Converts the weights between CuDNNLSTM and LSTM.

      Arguments:
        weights: Original weights.
        from_cudnn: Indicates whether original weights are from CuDNN layer.

      Returns:
        Updated weights compatible with LSTM.
      """


      # Transpose (and reshape) input and recurrent kernels
      kernels = transform_kernels(weights[0], transpose_input(from_cudnn),
                                  n_gates)
      recurrent_kernels = transform_kernels(weights[1], lambda k: k.T, n_gates)
      if from_cudnn:
        # merge input and recurrent biases into a single set
        biases = np.sum(np.split(weights[2], 2, axis=0), axis=0)
      else:
        # Split single set of biases evenly to two sets. The way of
        # splitting doesn't matter as long as the two sets sum is kept.
        biases = np.tile(0.5 * weights[2], 2)
      return [kernels, recurrent_kernels, biases]


    if source != target_class:
      weights = convert_lstm_weights(weights, from_cudnn=source == 'CuDNNLSTM')


  # convert the weights between CuDNNGRU and GRU(reset_after=True)
  if target_class in ['GRU', 'CuDNNGRU'] and len(weights) == 3:
    # We can determine the source of the weights from the shape of the bias.
    # If there is no bias we skip the conversion since
    # CuDNNGRU always has biases.


    units = weights[1].shape[0]
    bias_shape = weights[2].shape
    n_gates = 3


    def convert_gru_weights(weights, from_cudnn=True):
      """Converts the weights between CuDNNGRU and GRU.

      Arguments:
        weights: Original weights.
        from_cudnn: Indicates whether original weights are from CuDNN layer.

      Returns:
        Updated weights compatible with GRU.
      """


      kernels = transform_kernels(weights[0], transpose_input(from_cudnn),
                                  n_gates)
      recurrent_kernels = transform_kernels(weights[1], lambda k: k.T, n_gates)
      biases = np.array(weights[2]).reshape((2, -1) if from_cudnn else -1)
      return [kernels, recurrent_kernels, biases]


    if bias_shape == (2 * units * n_gates,):
      source = 'CuDNNGRU'
    elif bias_shape == (2, units * n_gates):
      source = 'GRU(reset_after=True)'
    elif bias_shape == (units * n_gates,):
      source = 'GRU(reset_after=False)'
    else:
      raise ValueError('Invalid bias shape: ' + str(bias_shape))


    if target_class == 'CuDNNGRU':
      target = 'CuDNNGRU'
    elif layer.reset_after:
      target = 'GRU(reset_after=True)'
    else:
      target = 'GRU(reset_after=False)'


    # only convert between different types
    if source != target:
      types = (source, target)
      if 'GRU(reset_after=False)' in types:
        raise ValueError('%s is not compatible with %s' % types)
      if source == 'CuDNNGRU':
        weights = convert_gru_weights(weights, from_cudnn=True)
      elif source == 'GRU(reset_after=True)':
        weights = convert_gru_weights(weights, from_cudnn=False)


  return weights
````

For my use case (putting `CuDNNGRU` weights into a `GRU`), the solution using this function is the following:

```py
# cudnn_gru and gru are built CuDNNGRU and GRU layers, respectively
kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias = _convert_rnn_weights(
    layer=gru,
    weights=[
        cudnn_gru.kernel.numpy(),
        cudnn_gru.recurrent_kernel.numpy(),
        cudnn_gru.bias.numpy(),
    ],
)
gru.cell.kernel.assign(kernel)
gru.cell.recurrent_kernel.assign(recurrent_kernel)
gru.cell.bias.assign(bias)
```

Note that to use the cuDNN-compatible implementation of `tf.keras.layers.GRU`, one must [use a specific combination of parameters](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py#L156-L164) (in particular, `use_bias=True`).

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit older, but may I add how one can convert CuDNNGRUs/CuDNNLSTMs to GRUs/LSTMs in Keras/TF 2.6 (the accepted answer didn't work for me, because the properties of the gru.cell seem to have changed).

Background: I wanted to train a CuDNNGRU using GPUs (faster than training standard GRU on GPU) and convert it into standard GRU for CPU inference.

This solution comes from a GitHub guy named [bzamecnik](https://gist.github.com/bzamecnik/bd3786a074f8cb891bc2a397343070f1):

1. Create model containing a CuDNNGRU `gru_cudnn` (or CuDNNLSTM), train it, and save it's weights:

   > ```
   > gru_cudnn = CuDNNGRU(n_units)
   > model = ... make model with gru_cudnn ...
   > model.fit(...)
   > model.save_weights('weights_cudnn.h5')
   > ```
2. Create a model with the same architecture using standard GRU `gru` (or LSTM) instead of CuDNNGRU (or CuDNNLSTM) and load the saved CuDNN weights from 1:

   > ```
   > gru = GRU(n_units, reset_after=True, recurrent_activation='sigmoid')
   > model = ... make model with gru ...
   > model.load_weights('weights_cudnn.h5')
   > ```

I hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this thread in the future.